# Curl command in bash script error

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to run a curl command within a bash script and I'm coming across the following error:

```
curl: (26) failed creating formpost data
```

When I echo the curl command and run that from the command line, that has no problems running. I've ensured there are read permissions for everyone on the file and the folder it's in, as well as using relative and absolute paths.

Here's a sample of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
usage(){
        echo "usage: <command> options: <u|p|f> "            
}

while getopts u:p:f: option
do
 case "${option}"
 in
 u) USERNAME=${OPTARG};;
 p) PORT=${OPTARG};;
 f) FILE=$OPTARG;;
 esac
done
if [ $OPTIND -eq 1 ]; then
        #echo "No options were passed";
        usage
        exit
fi

echo "Please enter your password:  "
read PASSWORD

TEST="curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -F file=@\"$FILE\" -F force=true -F install=true http://localhost:$PORT/test.jsp"

echo $TEST
$TEST
echo $?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the line of curl when you do `bash -x script.sh`

Comment: The curl command that runs in the script would be: `curl -u user:password -F 'file=@"package.zip"' -F force=true -F install=true http://localhost:4503/test.jsp`